# How to do case-insensitive String comparison in Oracle passing the Turkey Test?

Tags: sql, oracle, string-comparison, turkey-test

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Oracle SQL LIKE query case insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391069/make-oracle-sql-like-query-case-insensitive)

I want to do string comparison in SQL-Statements that ignore case. Currently we use something like `upper(field) like upper(anotherField)` and something like that. However this approach is known to fail the [Turkey test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796986/what-is-the-turkey-test), isn't it? How to do it the right way?

Comment: Are the answers given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389535/compare-strings-in-oracle) of any help?

Comment: @WolfgangFleischmann Not really. Maybe [NLS_COMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams120.htm) mentioned there will be helpful here. But I am pretty unsure ...